# Disable wp_enqueue_styles action for specific page

Tags: plugins

I have an specific page on my website where I can't have any stylesheets being enqueued, so I need to unenqueue all stylessheets loaded there. Problem is I don't know their IDs, because they can come from either several different themes or other plugins.

What I've tried to do is remove the wp_enqueue_styles action, but without luck.

Here's what I've tried:

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_enqueue_action', 99);
function remove_enqueue_action() {
    remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_styles','' );
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Follow up:

I also tried this without luck:

`<?php 
add_action('get_header', 'remove_widget_action');
function remove_widget_action() {
    remove_action( 'get_header', 'wp_enqueue_style',99 );
 remove_action( 'get_header', 'wp_register_style',99 ); 
}
?>`

Answer (score 1):

Check the `$wp_styles` global to get the stylesheet IDs.

```
global $wp_styles;
var_dump($wp_styles);
```

Look for the `handle` key. Or...

```
var_dump(array_keys($wp_styles->registered));
```

That should give you what you need to dequeue them.

Comment: Thank you but this does not list a style registered through the theme. 

IE:
    function woo_load_frontend_css () {wp_register_style( 'woo-layout', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/layout.css' );

  wp_enqueue_style( 'woo-layout' );
 } // End woo_load_frontend_css()

Comment: Yes, it does actually, if you run it _after_ the theme has registered the stylesheet.

Answer (score -1):

```
function dequeue_all () {
    global $wp_styles;
    // var_dump($wp_styles->queue);

    foreach ($wp_styles->queue as $handle) {
        wp_dequeue_style ($handle);
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'dequeue_all', 9999);
```

Working on that global vars cycling gives you a full array of all the styles loaded at the time you process the same one, so you can dequeue them all just specifying each handle.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why and how** could that solve the problem? See also: [answer]

Comment: Thank you @mirkolofio that successfully unenqueue all wp styles, but it didn't unenqueued the theme stylesheet.

Comment: @EduardoSoubihe Is it even enqueued? Or is the theme's stylesheet hard-coded in the theme's `header.php` file?

Comment: That's coz you need to run that code after the theme-code has run.

Try this one: [dequeue_all.php](https://gist.github.com/mirkolofio/b1674de42578ff4101d3)

This one should work 'cause it will be run after the theme il loaded, thanks to the hook at wp_footer.

Comment: Can you tell us if the purposed solution does the trick thank to the _wp_footer_ hook? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

it can be done where you are actually enqueue your scripts

like this

```
if(!is_page('page id on which you dont want styles') {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'functionname where you enqueue your style' );

}
```

Comment: This is not only about stylesheets enqueued by the user but about **all** of them. The question says "I can't have **any** stylesheets being enqueued"...